# Scala: get a value from a map using a variable?

Tags: scala, dictionary

I'm simply trying to get an Int value that's associated with a String key. I get:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Char
required: String
    score += tiles(letter)
```

from my code here:

```
val tiles = Map[String, Int](
    "a" -> 1,
    "b" -> 3,
    "c" -> 3,
    "d" -> 2
    // etc.
)

def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("\nScrabble Calculator 1.0")
    println("Enter words on the commandline.")
    println("Use a '_' character for blank tiles.\n")

    for (w <- args)  // loop through each word
        if (w.length < 2)
            println(w + ": one-letter words disallowed in Scrabble")
        else
            calculate(w)
}

def calculate(w: String) {
    var score = 0
    for (letter <- w)
        score += tiles(letter)
    println(w + ": " + score + " points")
}
```

If I do "a" or "b" instead of `letter`, it works fine (it returns 1, or 3, or whatever).

Comment: Won't this be a bit useless without taking into account bonus squares etc? Anyway, I made this more functional for you: https://gist.github.com/3615319

Comment: Awesome code. Not sure I understand it, but it's definitely 100x more elegant than mine. And yeah, I would have had to deal with score multipliers eventually. This was just a quick project to learn some Scala syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, jeez. It was a simple syntax problem. If you use ' instead of ", it is interpreted as a Char:

```
val tiles = Map[Char, Int](
    'a' -> 1,
    'b' -> 3,
    'c' -> 3,
    'd' -> 2,
```

Comment: FYI, that's the way it works in C, C++, C#, Haskell, Java, OCaml and probably many other languages as well.

Answer (score 1):

`tiles` is a `Map[String, Int]`.

`calculate` takes a `String` argument, `w`. It pulls individual characters out of `w` into `letter`, so `letter` is of type `Char`.

You then try to look up `letter` in `tiles`. `letter` is a `Char`, when `tiles` needs a `String`. This is **precisely** what the compiler is telling you with that error message.